# IAM Access Key permissions override an Explicit Deny in an IAM role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have an EC2 instance with a role with the following policy applied:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

With just the role applied, it works as expected - I can view the bucket contents but can't copy  objects to the bucket.

However, if I then add access keys for an IAM user with the `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy, the instance is able to copy objects to the bucket.

How is this allowed?  My understanding is that any explicit deny in any of the associated policies is final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because hard coded credentials have [higher priority](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html#cli-configure-quickstart-precedence)   then instance profile. Subsequently, your deny is not even considered in your scenario.

It would be better to put such deny in bucket policy, not instance role.

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it had to be documented somewhere.